# Android chat with PHP?

Tags: php, chat

I would like to implement a kind of chat. The client is Android and the server PHP.
Now I have some questions:
Is this kind of chat possible or what should be on server side? Is it recommandable to do a PHP request (maybe every second) to retrieve new data? What is the best way to realise it? What are pros and contras for php? What are good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't poll your server. Chat is realtime communication. Php is not built for this kind. Push the messages to android app. You can use php to run workers, process messages, deal with db things etc. you can look into Xmpp and message queues. Gcm might be helpful. It also supports upstream messaging.

Comment: But sending the messages to a database might work with php or are there problems? What is the recommended way? I think XMPP might work good.

Comment: You can send the data to php server. You have to do http calls for that. For each message in chat like system, you do a http call. And you poll the server for new messages. Try to use push messaging. It reduces the usage of battery, is realtime, can get presence of users, scalable etc

Comment: Last question: XMPP should work for push messaging? Maybe in combination with GCM?

Comment: Yes. May look into pub sub